# Why did Nightwing's costume change from black and blue to black and red in the DC New 52?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52

With the recent revamp of the DC comics, I noticed that Nightwing has changed his costume from black and blue to black and red. The only reason I can think of for this would be to sell toys. Does anyone know whether there is another reason?

[image]

Comment: I think it's just aesthetics. All franchises like to update their designs after a while to keep things fresh. Though the new Nightwing costume is very reminiscent of the Batman Beyond batsuit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the original [announcement](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/life/comics/2011-06-01-dc-comics-why-the-change_n.htm):

> The characters also are getting a makeover. While most of the specifics are still top secret, Lee says he worked with both staff and freelance artists to redesign costumes in a contemporary way as well as alter the physicality of many heroes and villains to modernize the DC Universe.

If you look at this [link](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/dc-comics-poll-pre-flashpoint-costumes-vs-new-52-costumes.452819393/) you'll see many (if not all) characters had costume design changed for the New 52.

The entire Batman lineup has a red theme now, with the exception of Batman himself and Batgirl (who has red hair).

[image]

The more red you have on your costume, the less likely you are to notice the blood as you bludgeon criminals in a dark alley.

It certainly appears that the changes came as a result of DC wanting to modernize all the characters and make them distinct from the previous continuity. That being said, I'm sure they weren't sad to also sell new toys.

Comment: +1, Yes, I agree the primary reason was to distance themselves from the previous continuity (selling new toys is a happy bonus as well).

Comment: Plus, it helped that fans liked the Damian Wayne Nightwing from Injustice: Gods Among Us.

Comment: Also, to sell toys.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because it is in a parallel universe and night wing is not dick Grayson he is Bruce Wayne's son Daymian Wanye who is evil in the parallel universe.

Comment: Can you support that with a point of reference?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of Nightwings; maybe one of them wanted a different color. There have been 5 Robins, and most of them became Nightwing for a short time and then moved on to something else

Answer (score 0):

Nightwing Changes From Blue Too Red, Because All The People That are in the Bat Family Have An Suit With Red in it, Except Batman and batgirl of course, And He(Dick Grayson) Turned Againt Batman, Thats how he became Nightwing, He changed too red when He Started Making Up With Batman And Joined The Bat Family Again And Turned Red Too Be More Aligned Too The Bat Family.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is an interesting theory; can you show how before and after the change correspond to his change of allegiance?

Comment: Please don't capitalise every single word, it makes it extremely hard to read what you're saying.

Answer (score -1):

I saw this on Facebook, and sounded good, but this isn't exactly my words.

Dick Grayson went to red because the wound that had separated him from Bruce for so long healed and rather rejecting the robin, he embraced it and returned to a more familiar color to have himself more align with the Bat-family.

Comment: Some references for your answer could help improve it.

Answer (score -1):

I have been told that the new costume changed because Damian Wayne killed Dick Grayson and dyed the logo red. It is just a new look for the comics. Also, in the new game Injustice Batman and Red Nightwing fight; before they fight Batman calls him Damian since he killed Dick in the parallel universe.

Comment: That's the story for the game, not the new 52.